# Como puedo leer el valor del estado de un componente hijo en React?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy realizando un renderizado condicional de 3 componentes que son formularios (login, registro, olvide mi contraseña) pero el componente registro renderiza a otros dos formularios (cliente o proveedor) por medio de un renderizado condicional tambien. lo que quiero hacer es leer un valor que se encuentra en el estado del componente registro desde el componente padre que renderiza a los 3 componentes (login, registro, olvide mi contraseña).

Alguna solucion a este problema?

**Estado del componente hijo:**

```
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('Cliente');
```

**Condicional Para renderizar componentes:**

```
const LoginOrRegister = () => {
      if(state.Login){
        return (<Login></Login>)
        
      }else if (state.Registro){
        return (<TabsRegistro ></TabsRegistro>)

      }else if(state.RecoveryPassword){
        return (<RecuperarContraseña></RecuperarContraseña>) 
      }else{
        return null;
      }
    };
```

TabsRegistro es el componente que contiene los otros dos componentes que es el formulario de cliente o proveedor.

Comment: Podrías hacer que el componente `LoginOrRegister` se haga cargo de enviar los datos cuando sean necesarios. Es decir, `LoginOrRegister` pasa un método como `handleRegisterOrLogin` como props al registro. Después registro pasa ese mismo método que le llego en los props como un prop a los componentes de Cliente y de Proveedor.

¿Para que requieres saber el estado de un componente hijo?

Comment: Ellos se renderizan en un modal, pero necesito saber si es proveedor o cliente en el estado del hijo para asi poner el condicional del tamaño del modal ya que uno es mas extenso que el otro.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner en la pregunta el código del componente de registro?

Comment: Si necesitas hacer muchas consultas de estados desde componentes padres a hijos, podría servirte aprender a usar [Context](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) o [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)

Comment: Puedes utilizar los manejadores de estado como te dijo @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza o también crear el estado en el componente padre y enviar los cambiadores y estados de él a los componentes hijos.